# decorator with current user is admin

Tags: flask, python-decorators

I m trying to add a decorator like this

```
def requires_admin(f):
    def wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            #if not admin:
                flash('You are not authorize to this page')
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

My User model have this field:
admin = db.Column(Boolean)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studying the implemention of [login_required](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/main/flask_login/utils.py#L234) in `flask_login` might be useful here. A quick glance shows that your snippet uses an extra layer of wrapper, and a read of theirs shows some edge cases that you might want to consider.